# Tooltip using Title attribute in IE 11

Tags: html, attributes, title, imagemap

I have created an image map and am trying to get a tooltip when hovering over the mapped areas.  I know IE requires the use of the title attribute.  I have constructed what seems to work fine in Chrome but I get no tooltip other than the one marked "test6" in the below code:

```
<map name="Map" id="Map">
    <area alt="test" title="test" href="#" shape="poly" coords="52,294.75,90.8599853515625,295.32000732421875,134.8599853515625,333.6099853515625,136.57000732421875,403.8900146484375,6.2899932861328125,402.75,8,333.02996826171875" />
    <area alt="test2" title="test2" href="#" shape="poly" coords="191.42999267578125,294.17999267578125,230.28997802734375,294.17999267578125,276,332.4599609375,277.1399841308594,402.17999267578125,146.28997802734375,403.8900146484375,144,331.32000732421875" />
    <area alt="test3" title="test3" href="#" shape="poly" coords="332,295.32000732421875,372.57000732421875,293.6099853515625,416,333.6099853515625,417.1400146484375,405.6099853515625,288,402.17999267578125,285.7099914550781,332.4599609375" />
    <area alt="test4" title="test4" href="#" shape="poly" coords="472.57000732421875,294.17999267578125,514.8599853515625,294.17999267578125,559.4299926757812,334.75,558.2899780273437,403.8900146484375,430.28997802734375,404.4599609375,428.57000732421875,332.4599609375" />
    <area alt="test5" title="test5" href="#" shape="poly" coords="613.1399536132812,295.32000732421875,653.7099609375,295.8900146484375,699.4299926757812,334.75,700,402.75,570.2899780273437,403.8900146484375,568.5700073242187,331.8900146484375" />
    <area alt="test6" title="test6" href="#" shape="rect" coords="272,85.02999877929687,448.57000732421875,149.02999877929687" />
</map>
```

Is there something else that I am missing here?  They all work fine in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, who would have thought.  Browser was zoomed in to 125% and it caused all sorts of issues with the tooltip.  If anyone else has this issue the answer is to zoom to the normal 100% and it will work fine after that.