# Title attribute not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I just want to ask what's wrong with my program. Im doing this program where I have to choose a file. But the button is an image and I would like to add a tooltip that this image is for selecting a file. This block of codes is perfectly working in chrome. But when I run it in IE11 the title "Select File"is not showing  in IE11. I didn't know that IE has a lot of restriction. Unlike in chrome.

```css
  .image-upload>input {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 0px;
  height: 0px;
  margin: -10%;
}

div.item {
  vertical-align: top;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  img {
    width: 90px;
    height: 50px;
  }
  .caption {
    display: block;
    color: white;
  }
  div.space {
    margin-top: -15px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
  <label for="file-input">
    <p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="black" size = "5"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSelect File&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp </b><span style="cursor:pointer" alt="Select File" title="Select File">
    <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/Folder/Black%20glamour/Files.ico" style="pointer-events: none" id="img" title="Select File"/></span></font></p></label>
  </label>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)" onclick=getName() required>
</div>
```

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36606868/tooltip-using-title-attribute-in-ie-11 applicable?

Comment: My program is about executing a python script that's why I use php

Comment: There is nothing related to python or PHP in your code

Comment: It is because you have set pointer events none - your mouse should have no effect on the element

Comment: @apokryfos nope I done putting the alt and title still in IE no tooltip is shown :(

Comment: That's some of the worst markup I've ever seen. Why use style sheets and then have inline style? What's the point of the useless `font` and `b` tags when you have css? And what's with the string of `&nbsp;`? Really? Clean that stuff up and pay attention to the comment by @Pete.

Comment: I've made this https://jsfiddle.net/qxwarqrb/ and the title is not showing in Chrome either. Removing pointer events fixes it.

Comment: @Pete when I changed the pointer events to all. When I run it in IE the image is not clickable anymore

Comment: @KimBuenaseda see my updated answer below (with your code in a bit more of a valid state)

Comment: The `<font>` element and `align` property are obsolete. Don't use those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the inline style of `pointer-events:none` from the image tag if you want to be able to hover it.

By setting it to none, it means your mouse can't interact with the element and therefore it cannot hover it to show the title.

Try this:

```
<img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/Folder/Black%20glamour/Files.ico"  id="img" title="Select File"/>
```

[Example fiddle showing with and without pointer events](https://jsfiddle.net/mz2u1uth/)

[More information about pointer events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events?v=control)

Also please note the following errors with your code:

- the font tag is obsolete and should not be used - use css instead
- &nbsp should have a semi colon after it: `&nbsp;`
- there is an extra end label and I don't think you are allowed p tags inside - use a validator to check your code

```html
<div class="image-upload">
  <p align="left"><label for="file-input"><b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Select File&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; </b>
    </label></p>
  <span style="cursor:pointer; display:inline-block;" alt="Select File" title="Select File"><label for="file-input"><img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/Folder/Black%20glamour/Files.ico" id="img" title="Select File"/>
  </label></span>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)" onclick=getName() required>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could add another `span` ( for example ), give it position absolute, and on hover on the image, show it .

you can also you javascript ( jquery ) to show it in the same position your cursor is, but that's a bit more complicated.

See below if this is what you want

```css
.title {
  transition: 0.3s ease-out;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.wrapper:hover .title {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-upload">
  <label for="file-input">
    <p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="black" size="5"><b>&nbsp&nbsp&nbspSelect File&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp </b>        <span class="wrapper" style="cursor:pointer" alt="Select File" title="Select File">
  <span class="title">Select File</span>
    <img src="http://icons.veryicon.com/ico/Folder/Black%20glamour/Files.ico" style="pointer-events: none" id="img" title="Select File"/></span></font></p>

  </label>
  </label>
  <input id="file-input" type="file" name="file" onchange="onFileSelected(event)" onclick=getName() required>
</div>
```